# Firebase data to HTML affects styling

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

am displaying data on html table from firbase realtime database using Javascript, which works fine, except that it takes away the table styling and also part of the page styling.

```
var id = 0;
   var urlRef = firebase.database().ref("/");
     urlRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
        var name = data.val().Name;
        var phone = data.val().Phone;
        var email = data.val().Email;
        var amount = data.val().Amount;
        var sendoption = data.val().Sendoption;
        var number = data.val().Number;
        var package = data.val().Package;
        var datetime = data.val().Date

        id++;
        
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + id + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + package + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + format(amount) + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + number+ '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + sendoption + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + email + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + phone + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + datetime + '</td>';

        content += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#table').append(content);
```

Comment: Can you share some screenshots in order to see what is broken?

Comment: Without an example, it's hard to tell what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Where is the styling supposed to come from? Also, JS runtime error, `content` is not defined

Comment: One comment is that you should be appending to the `tbody`, not the `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the styling in the css by providing the tags with the relevant class.

Here is an example of another way to update/populate the table in javascript, which replace the existing HTML. Do some modification to fit your case.

html:

```
<thead>
     <tr>
     <th>No.</th>
     <th>Host</th>
     <th>Players Waiting</th>
     <th>Join Game</th>
     <th>Password</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="game-details">
      <tr><td colspan="5">No game</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

javascript:

```
con.on('UpdateList', list => {
        let html = '';
        var i = 1;
        for (let game of list) {
            html += `
                <tr id="game_table">
                    <td id="game_list">${i}</td>
                    <td id="game_list">something here</td>
                    <td id="game_list">something here</td>
                    <td id="game_list">something here</td>
                    <td id="game_list">something here</td>
                </tr>
            `;
        i++;
    }

    $('.game-details').html(html);
    });
```

Comment: A loop where each iteration creates 5 tds with the same ID?

Comment: each of the 5 tds has same styling but with different purposes. I delete my code to avoid confusion.